# iOS 11 basic authentication fails

Tags: http, url, mobile-safari, basic-authentication, ios11

I have a URL that incorporates basic authentication such as: https://user:pass@stagingsite.com

When i load this site on devices with iOS 10.3.3 and lower it works fine and I am able to proceed to the main page.

However, when i load this exact same URL with a device that has iOS 11.x then the safari browser asks for the site authentication credentials. Ive dug around a bit in the new iOS 11 settings and nothing was resolving it.

It looks like for iOS 11.x in the safari browser URL field when https://user:pass@stagingsite.com is entered and loaded, it redirects to https://stagingsite.com does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?